# Jquery remove class add to next

Tags: jquery, class

I have two methods to select an li with class and remove that class, find next li and add the class to it

method 1:

```
$nxt=$(".current");
$(".current").removeClass("current");
$nxt.next().addClass("current");
```

method 2:

```
  $('.current').removeClass(function(){
  $(this).next().addClass('current');
  return 'current';
  }
```

I want to use the second one but unfortunately,it doesn't work for me!
Plz help me

http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/pa7aU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just missing a closing bracket?

```
$('.current').removeClass(function(){
  $(this).next().addClass('current');
  return 'current';
  })
```

It appears to work here - http://jsfiddle.net/ujTDp/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a class as parameter and not a function.

```
$('.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pa7aU/1/

If you need the new current object, then you can use `$('.current')`once again.